# Scrapy Spider with dynamically called Spider does not save any output to desired folder

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to run "___SPIDER_RUNNER.py" by hitting F5 in Visual Studio code. All seems to crawl ok, logging shows that items are being retrieved, but the output JSON file is not saved to folder C:\scrapy\JSON_output.
That folder exists. I have write persmissions.

I'm completely stuck as no errors are logged.

I tried different paths in file _singlepage_nonAJAX.py:

```
    'FEED_URI': 'C:/scrapy/JSON_output/test.json'
    'FEED_URI': r'C:\scrapy\JSON_output\test.json'
    'FEED_URI': f'C:\\scrapy\\JSON_output\\{self.name}.json'
```

I tried removing ITEM_PIPELINES and FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS settings from settings.py

My folder structure is as follows:

```
- C:\scrapy\my_spiders\___SPIDER_RUNNER.py
- C:\scrapy\my_spiders\__init__.py
- C:\scrapy\my_spiders\spiders\__init__.py
- C:\scrapy\my_spiders\spiders\_singlepage_nonAJAX.py
```

All "**init**.py" files contain no code.

**___SPIDER_RUNNER.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\scrapy')
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from my_spiders.spiders._singlepage_nonAJAX import SinglePageNonAJAXSpider
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def run_spider(myname, start_urls, SERP_item, url, itemstatus, okstatus, title):
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    process.crawl(SinglePageNonAJAXSpider, 
                  myname=myname, 
                  start_urls=start_urls, 
                  SERP_item=SERP_item, 
                  url=url, 
                  itemstatus=itemstatus, 
                  okstatus=okstatus, 
                  title=title)
    process.start()

run_spider("toscrape", 
           "https://quotes.toscrape.com",
            "//div[@class='quote']/span/a[starts-with(@href, '/author/')]",
            "./@href",
            ""''"",
            "", 
            '//span[contains(@class, "author-born-date")]/text()')
```

**_singlepage_nonAJAX.py**

```
import json
import re
import os
import scrapy
import time
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from lxml import html

class RentalItem(scrapy.Item):
    city = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field() 

class SinglePageNonAJAXSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'whatever'

    def __init__(self, myname=None, start_urls=None, SERP_item=None, url=None, itemstatus=None, okstatus=None, title=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SinglePageNonAJAXSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if myname:
            self.name = myname
        if start_urls:
            self.start_urls = [start_urls]  # Assuming only one URL
        self.SERP_item = SERP_item
        self.url = url
        self.itemstatus = itemstatus
        self.okstatus = okstatus
        self.title = title

        # Update 2: update the FEEDS value with the modified 'name'
        self.custom_settings['FEEDS'] = {
            f'\\scrapy\\JSON_output\\{self.name}.json': {
                'format': 'json',
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'fields': None,
                'indent': 4,
                'item_export_kwargs': {
                    'export_empty_fields': True,
                },
            },
        }




    def parse(self, response):
        for listing in response.xpath(self.SERP_item):
            listing_url = listing.xpath(self.url).get()
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=response.urljoin(listing_url), 
                callback=self.parse_object,
            )

    def parse_object(self, response):
        item = RentalItem()
        item['url'] = response.url # get url
        item['city'] = 'mycity'
        yield item
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import json

class MyCustomPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.items = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):            
        self.items.append(dict(item))
        return item
```

**middlewares.py**

```
from scrapy import signals
from itemadapter import is_item, ItemAdapter

class MySpiderMiddleware:
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
        return None

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        for i in result:
            yield i

    def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
        pass

    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        for r in start_requests:
            yield r

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)

class MyDownloaderMiddleware:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        pass

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'my_spiders'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['my_spiders.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'my_spiders.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_useragents.downloadermiddlewares.useragents.UserAgentsMiddleware': 500,
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
} 

from shutil import which
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless']


#Configure item pipelines. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'my_spiders.pipelines.MyCustomPipeline': 300,
}

FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = [
'id', 'url', 'city', 'title'
]

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/' 
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried both settings.py and custom_settings to set your setting.
But in both cases it still does not use my desired file output name.

When I set this in `settings.py` and execute `___SPIDER_RUNNER.py`:

```
FEEDS = {
    'items.json': {
        'format': 'json',
        'encoding': 'utf8',
        'fields': None,
        'indent': 4,
        'item_export_kwargs': {
            'export_empty_fields': True,
        },
    },
}
```

not output file is stored at all.

When I remove "FEEDS" from settings and add to class `SinglePageNonAJAXSpider` instead:

```
custom_settings = {
    'FEEDS': {
        f'{format}.json': {  # using spider name
            'format': 'json',
            'encoding': 'utf8',
            'fields': None,
            'indent': 4,
            'item_export_kwargs': {
                'export_empty_fields': True,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

It always stores filename `whatever.json`, even though from my `___SPIDER_RUNNER.py` I pass the desired filename "my_filename_variable":

```
run_spider("my_filename_variable", 
           "https://quotes.toscrape.com",
            "//div[@class='quote']/span/a[starts-with(@href, '/author/')]",
            "./@href",
            ""''"",
            "", 
            '//span[contains(@class, "author-born-date")]/text()')
```

I checked your reference page on feeds, but I can't figure out what I need to change.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete all previous settings about FEEDS
2. Use `settings.py` or `custom_settings` for set your setting.

For `settings.py`:

```
FEEDS = {
    'items.json': {
        'format': 'json',
        'encoding': 'utf8',
        'fields': None,
        'indent': 4,
        'item_export_kwargs': {
            'export_empty_fields': True,
        },
    },
}
```

For `custom_settings`:

```
class SinglePageNonAJAXSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'whatever'
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            f'{name}.json': {  # using spider name
                'format': 'json',
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'fields': None,
                'indent': 4,
                'item_export_kwargs': {
                    'export_empty_fields': True,
                },
            },
        },
    }

    def __init__...
```

3. Run spider, which return some items.
4. Finish it or expect to finalize.
5. Check, that your data writed in root scrapy folder in items.json file.
6. If it ok, then try to add your path ('`C:\scrapy\JSON_output\test.json`') instead '`items.json`'

It should help you. If this is not the case then check your settings in the spider's `__init__` method via `self.crawler.settings`

More about FEED settings:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=FEED#settings

Comment: That works, like so "'\\scrapy\\JSON_output\\test.json'". Now how could I use the name of the spider in the filename? I tried this:

 f'\\scrapy\\JSON_output\\{name}.json': {

But in my __init__ function that name is overwritten (like I want it to). However when I move your `custom_settings` logic into the __init__ function the JSON file is no longer saved.

Comment: Why do you need to use spider name reassignment?
In the classic use case, spider doesn't expect its name to change, so I'm guessing you might be doing something wrong.

The settings are initialized before the _init_ method is executed. If you are confident in your actions, you can try updating the FEEDS setting in self.crawler.settings.

If it doesnt help, then you will need to write your own custom spider middleware. However, I advise you to still reconsider the structure of your program. Perhaps you should split the spiders into base and child logic through inheritance

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply, I was out.
Per your question, I want to execute the `run_spider` method multiple times for different sites, and for each I want the name I pass to it be the filename. That's it really.
So if I understand you correctly, the custom_settings variable is set BEFORE the init method is called, so I'd expect the `self.name = myname` to overwrite those settings. 
I've added the code in update 2 to my `__init__` function, however, it STILL saves as file "whatever.json", even though `self.name` AND the FEEDS variables contains updated name. Why is that happening?

Comment: Check my updated variant of custom_settings with f'{name}.json', it can be solve your task.

And rule of good form in Scrapy is that all spiders are given a static name. If you have 2 spiders with different names, then you must create 2 different spiders, which, if necessary, will inherit from the same logic

Comment: Thanks! I added update 2 with some further info, if you could have another look please? I'd rather not create a copy of each Spider when the code logic is similar and I'll likely need ~100 spiders, so I think inheriting would not make sense then?

Comment: When you add the result to settings.py, but it doesn’t work for you, it turns out that the settings are either created or overridden in some place. When you use custom_settings, the problem is that the settings are always created before the spider's init method. So you can only try to change the changes in self.crawler.settings in the init method, but I can't get it to work.

If the logic of 100 spiders is similar, then most likely you want to do something wrong. You can manage 100 spider instances and they will run in 100 different processes. try to figure out why you need 100 spiders

Comment: The reason I'm saying I want 100 spiders is because there are 100 different websites that I need to crawl. The websites may differ slightly (e.g. CSS selector for price element, or photos element) and of course the JSON output filename that the spider produces, so the scrape logic is the same but specific parameters are different. Is that not a valid approach/use case?

Comment: No, this is not quite the right approach when using spiders. If you need to crawl different sites, but you have the same type of end data, you need to create and fill in a single Scrapy Item and Spider Pipeline for all your spiders. If the link traversal logic is very similar, then you can use the webpoet library or define a basic spider for the general parsing logic. But scrapy assumes that each domain should be cleaned by a separate spider class. This way you will have the correct operation of the spider, for example, the correct operation of the allowed_domains parameter, etc.

Comment: Ah, that is very good to know! I think the basic spider you suggest is the best option then. I presume I then need to somehow inherit from that basic spider when creating my classes for each target website. Could you point me to an example of this so I can take it from there? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't have a public example. The necessary information can be obtained from the scrapy documentation or from a video on youtube. You need to create 1 scrapy pipeline and 1 scrapy item for one type of data. For example, this will most likely be one ProductItem with attributes such as price, description, title, etc.
Creating basic spider logic is one of the typical Python tasks of inheritance and overriding. Everything that is the same must be moved to the base spider, and special cases of logic must be redefined(overrided)

Comment: Or you can use github for get examples or download book about Scrapy

Comment: I created a new question as a follow-up, would you mind having a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77408636/inherited-scrapy-spider-does-not-store-any-output-from-super-basic-tutorial-site