# Inherited Scrapy spider does not store any output from super basic tutorial site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

See the full Scrapy project filenames and code below.
It creates 2 output files myspecificspider.json AND myspecificspider_items.json (which is weird on its own as I'd expect only the latter), but more importantly neither of the files contain ANY content.
I can't figure out what's wrong here. Te debug log shows no errors and the CSS selector (tested in a separate non-inherited Spider) works. Does it have to do with my inheritance logic perhaps?

**pipelines.py**

```
import json

class MyCustomPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.items = []
    def process_item(self, item, spider):            
        self.items.append(dict(item))
        return item

class JsonPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        filename = f'{spider.name}_items.json'
        self.file = open(filename, 'w')
    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

**basespider.py**

```
import scrapy
from ..myitems import MyItem
from my_spiders.globalfunctions import *

class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'my_spiders.pipelines.JsonPipeline': 300,}
    }
    allowed_domains = ['test.com']
    start_urls = ['']
    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

**myitems.py**

```
import scrapy
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field() 
    city = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**myspecificspider.py**

```
import scrapy
import json
import re
import os
import time
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from lxml import html
from typing import TypedDict
from scrapy import signals
from my_spiders.globalfunctions import *
from ..myconfig import *
from ..myitems import MyItem
from my_spiders.spiders.basespider import BaseSpider

class MySpecificSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'myspecificspider'
    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com']
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    debug = False

    def parse(self, response):
        total_found = 0
        for listing in response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']/span/a[starts-with(@href, '/author/')]"):
            listing_url = listing.xpath("./@href").get()
            listing_url = "https://quotes.toscrape.com" + listing_url #create a fully qualified URL
            print(listing_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=response.urljoin(listing_url), 
                callback=self.parse_object,
            )


    def parse_object(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url # get url
        item['city'] = 'test'
        item['status'] = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "author-born-date")]/text()').get()
        print("Extracted Item:", item)  
        yield item
```

Comment: Probably because you have not declared a `start_urls` attribute or `start_requests` method so the spider doesn't know where to start

Comment: @Alexander thank you!! It was the start_urls variable (updated in my code). Now it shows output. Do you know why it saves 2 files `myspecificspider.json` and `myspecificspider_items.json`? I'd want and expect only the latter since that's what's defined in my `pipelines.py` class `JsonPipeline`...

Comment: probably because you specifying the other on the command line